# Drop elements from pandas series having index starting with a particular word

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series, as shown below.

```
vol = pd.Series([1,0,-3,2,5],index=['Jan, 15','Oct, 17','Apr, 18','Sep, 19', 'Jan, 18'])    
print(vol)
    Jan, 15    1
    Oct, 17    0
    Apr, 18   -3
    Sep, 19    2
    Jan, 18    5
    dtype: int64
```

If I need to drop an element with a known `index`, I can use [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html#pandas.Series.drop) function, but here I must know the `index`. How can I detete the elements whose index start with `Jan`? I want the following -

```
print(vol)
    Oct, 17    0
    Apr, 18   -3
    Sep, 19    2
    dtype: int64
```

Function .[`filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.filter.html#pandas.Series.filter) was close, for example -

```
print(vol.filter(like='Jan'))
    Jan, 15    1
    Jan, 18    5
    dtype: int64
```

But, `vol.filter(like != 'Jan')` doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, You can write it in answer section so that I can uptick it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already mentioned all the pieces, you can just do:

```
vol.drop(vol.filter(like='Jan').index)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
s = vol[~vol.index.str.startswith('Jan')]
print (s)
Oct, 17    0
Apr, 18   -3
Sep, 19    2
dtype: int64
```

For check values in index (not only start position) use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
s = vol[~vol.index.str.contains('Jan')]
print (s)
Oct, 17    0
Apr, 18   -3
Sep, 19    2
dtype: int64
```

Alternative with `filter`:

```
s = vol.filter(regex=r'^(?!.*Jan).*$')
print (s)
Oct, 17    0
Apr, 18   -3
Sep, 19    2
dtype: int64
```